# How to implode $_POST with comma and quotes around each element?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm wanting to filter search results with ajax request for WP Query.
Works for single checked option then breaks on 2nd option checked.
Example data-values: apartments, townhomes

**jQuery / AJAX**:

```
category = [];
                jQuery('.rpd_category:checked').each(function() {
                    category.push(jQuery(this).attr('data-value'));                                            
                });

data: {
      'category_values'   :   [category],
},

console.log(category) = ["apartments", "townhomes"]
```

**PHP**:

```
$taxcateg_include =  $_POST['category_values'];

 $categ_array=array(
            'taxonomy' => 'property_category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( $taxcateg_include ),
        );

echo $taxcateg_include = apartments,townhomes
```

I want to add single quotes to each elements and seperate elements by comma and space ", " ..

**Goal:**

```
 'terms' => array( 'apartments', 'townhomes' ),
```

I tried using implode but doesn't work? Is `$_POST['category_values']`returning elements as a string?

Should I be doing something different in jQuery?

Thanks for any answers and/or direction!

Comment: You definitely not understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Please show us what errors you are getting and expected output.

Comment: I know what I want to achieve.. just lost on how to accomplish it. Sorry I haven't had much experience with any of this..

Answer (score 0):

you are over complicating things wrapping existing arrays in outer array both in your javascript and in the php

in javascript change:

```
data: {
      'category_values'   :   [category],
}
```

To

```
data: {
      'category_values'   :   category// this is already an array you pushed to
}
```

In php you don't need to create a new array that will be exactly the same as the array you already have.

```
$taxcateg_include =  $_POST['category_values'];// is already an array 

 $categ_array=array(
            'taxonomy' => 'property_category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' =>  $taxcateg_include // is array
        );
```

Comment: Ok thanks, when I change it to your example above and then echo $taxcateg_include = townhomes  with both options checked looking for ( 'apartments', 'townhomes' )

Comment: that's not very clear...is it what you need or not? if not you also should show more of the ajax code

Comment: Sorry, no it seems to only include the 2nd option checked and drops the 1st element.. so instead of ( 'apartments', 'townhomes' ) only townhomes is listed once they second checkbox is checked

Comment: sounds like something wrong in the UI or timing when you create the javascript array. Need to provide [mcve]. A demo that does all but the ajax would help. Also last statement conflicts with what you show being logged in the question

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to do. You want to convert the POSTed string into an array and add it to `$categ_array['terms']`, correct? Try this out:

```
// Assuming $_POST['category_values'] === 'apartments,townhomes';
$taxcateg_include =  explode(',' $_POST['category_values']);
$categ_array= array(
    'taxonomy' => 'property_category',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => $taxcateg_include
);
```